# To count elements in a table and to show the quantity with grid.CGridView using Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a question about how to count elements of a table and to show them using grid.CGridView.

I have two tables, teachers (id, teachername) and students (id, teacher_id, name, reg_date -a datatime register-).

This two tables are related with a foreing key, so the document \protected\models\students.php include:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    'teacher' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Teachers', 'teacher_id'),
            );
    }
```

I would like to show a row for each teacher, where each column will be his id, teachername, the number of teacher's students, last student enrolled in the course and enrollment date (I mean, the student reg_date).

I have a grid.CGridView in the document \protectec\views\Teachers\index.ph

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
            'id',
            'teachername'
    ),
)); ?>
```

So I would like to know that I have to write in the grid.CGridView to show those elements. As you can see, I do't know how to reference the another table.

Please, I need you help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Teacher model add these relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'students'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Student', 'teacher_id'),
        'studentCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'Student', 'teacher_id'),
        'lastStudent'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Student', 'teacher_id', 'order'=>'reg_date desc'),
    );
}
```

In the grids view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
            'id',
            'teachername',
            'studentCount',
            'lastStudent.name',
            'lastStudent.regDate'
    ),
));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks HarryFink, I can show the table with the widget, but the last columns, studentCount, 'lastStudent.name' and 'lastStudent.reg_date' are empty...Do you know what is the problem? By the way, I used the right name of the clases, Students, with S in the end and reg_dete, instead of regDate, but it didn't work well either....

Comment: Sorry I meant to say reg_date instead of regDate. Besides I didn't delete the relations BELONGS_TO, since the result was the same.

Comment: Ok! I wrote the relations in the Student model...I think that everything works well, THANK YOU VERY MUCH